# Webpack: How do I include a node module's css?

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation, webpack, vue.js

I am using [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) to scaffold a Vue.js + Webpack app and am confused how to, as a basic example, include something like [Zurb Foundation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foundation-sites).

I have installed required dependencies and loaders such as `sass-loader` and `css-loader` but am just confused on a fundamental level of understanding how one can configure Webpack to compile and include, for example `node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss`

In my webpack config I have:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"],
      include: projectRoot
    } ...
```

In my basic `App.vue` component I have:

```
<style src="./scss/app.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

And in my `app.scss` I have tried, to no avail:

```
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';
```

(among many other syntactically incorrect attempts that threw errors)

I believe I'm missing something fundamental about the way Webpack works with npm or bower packages. Any direction would be greatly appreciated as this seems to be a simple problem without a clear answer that I can find.

Copying required files over from node_modules seems like an illogical or not so ideal solution as well.

Comment: I believe you require (or import perhaps, I haven't tried that) the .scss in the javascript. See the [webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html). The js is then bundled (packed, if you will) in with the js blob. When the js require() is called on the .scss in code, webpack will put the style onto the page. no style src= tag at all

Comment: hm, in my `main.js` I've tried `require("!style!css!sass!../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss");` which compiles but still doesn't load any styles (nor seems ideal in terms of having to so explicitly state the path?). Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: not sure its the same with css but I use themes for sweetalert like that:
require('sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css')
require('sweetalert/themes/google/google.css')
and of course you need right loader in webpack config

Comment: @import is not going to work runing dev as this loads the file from browser and then you are limited to `src` folder, but probably if you run `npm run build` it will include the css compiled file in the `dist` folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't change anything to my Webpack config. I did it like this:

Note: my project's components are in a 'src/components' folder and my app.scss directly in the src folder. I am using foundation-sites v6.2.2 and vue-cli 2.2.0.

In a base component I have this:

```
<style src="../app.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

Now in this app.scss I pasted everything from node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/settings/_settings.scss to enable customization.
You will have to change one line there:

`@import 'util/util';`

should become:

`@import '~foundation-sites/scss/util/util';`

Finally add two lines at the very bottom of your app.scss:

```
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';
@include foundation-everything;
```

This should cover your css.

However you will likely need to do something about javascript too, because Foundation's javascript components require some initialization. I haven't done that myself yet, but this might be helpful: http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/893/vue-js-foundation-6/6

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this a bit. Perfect answer!